# Progress bar during smbclient put

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to show a progress bar during a remote copy using smbclient put, maybe using **pv** or **dialog**, or any other option.

The smbclient-put command il working fine:

```
smbclient //usbrouter/backup --user=myusername mypassword -c "put /media/DOC/BackupAuto/work_backup.tar.gz work_backup.tar.gz"
```

But I can't find any way the show the progress of the copy. Anyone have a solution/alternative?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What I do when I want to check up on a file transfer operation that either doesn't support progress bars or I forgot to start it in a progress bar mode is this.

Figure out the total size of your local copy of the file (`work_backup.tar.gz`) e.g. with `ls`, `stat` or `du`. Then go to the location of the target file (either with `ssh` or just `cd` if it' on the same machine). Issue

```
watch -- du -h work_backup.tar.gz
```

This is a bit hacky, but it still works even after starting the respective copy job and it pretty much works with every copy mechanism I can imagine.

Comment: I used this to monitor a large file being downloaded with smbclient. Can't stand that get command with no feedback. Thanks :)

Comment: Same here. I am testing now smbclient download speeds, since the GUI speeds are very low.

Comment: what is the `--` for?

Comment: It's a commonly used parameter to indicate that the parameter-list is now ended. It's probably not really necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned `pv` is perfect for the job:

```sh
file="work_backup.tar.gz"
pv "/media/DOC/BackupAuto/${file}" \
  | smbclient \
    --user=myusername%mypassword \
    --command "put - '${file}'" \
    //usbrouter/backup
```

Or in the reverse, to pull with progress:

```sh
file="work_backup.tar.gz"
size="$( \
  smbclient \
    --user=myusername%mypassword \
    --command "ls '${file}'" \
    //usbrouter/backup \
    2> /dev/null \
    | grep "${file}" \
    | awk '{print $3}')"

smbclient \
  --stderr \
  --user=myusername%mypassword \
  --command "get '${file}' /dev/stdout" \
  //usbrouter/backup \
  | pv -s "${size}" \
  > "/media/DOC/BackupAuto/${file}"
```

*Obligatory side note: you should not specify password like this, use one of the other options like `--authentication-file` instead*